# Delete rows with VB after background query has run - Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Please help - I've been searching for hours and am having no luck!
I'm using Power Query to bring in results from a SQL script. This information updates everytime I open the spreadsheet. Once the information has updated, I would like to delete Rows which have a date in Column C that is greater than today, so they don't get calculated in my VLOOKUP on another sheet. 
I've tried the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim LR As Long, I As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
LR = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For I = LR To 1 Step -1
    If Range("C" & I).Value > Date Then Rows(I).Delete
Next I
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

This however doesn't run automatically, and when running it manually it gives "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" and then proceeds to delete incorrect dates.

I also tried this, but it also deletes the incorrect dates and gives me Run-time error.

```
Sub DeleteCells()
Dim LR As Long, I As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
LR = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For I = LR To 1 Step -1
If Range("C" & I).Value > Date Then Rows(I).Delete
Next I
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) what line of code gives you an error. 2) how your dates are stored in the sheet (I mean as dates or as text, if is text - what is the format)?

Comment: 1) line of code: 
If Range("C" & I).Value > Date + 1 Then Rows(I).Delete               
2) dates are in date format

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code..can you post screen of your data (especially column C)?

Comment: @simoco Don't have enough rep to post screen yet - try this link? http://postimg.org/image/j00amljih/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT 4/11: I am guessing that the 1004 error occurred because all of the "Branch Not Open" rows had been previously removed. The updated code below wraps an `if` statement around the autofilter step, which should now only be applied if at least one match for "Branch Not Open" is found in the filter range. Hopefully this version works!

@SickDimension is off to a great start -- but since you know that a number of rows are going to have "Branch Not Open" listed in the "Live Date" column you can remove them quickly using the `autofilter`. Try this code out (with an update for the `LR` code too):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim LR As Long, LC As Long, I As Long
Dim FilterRng As Range
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'assign worksheet to save time in references
Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Clocking Exceptions")

'Define your filter range as the block of data
LC = DataSheet.Range("A3").End(xlToRight).Column
With DataSheet
    LR = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set FilterRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(3, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LR, LC))

'autofilter the sheet to remove "Branch Not Open" rows
If Not FilterRng.Find(What:="Branch Not Open", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
    With FilterRng
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Branch Not Open", Operator:=xlAnd
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    DataSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If

For I = LR To 1 Step -1
    If IsDate(DataSheet.Range("C" & I).Value) Then
        If DateValue(DataSheet.Range("C" & I).Value) > DateValue(Date) Then Rows(I).Delete
    End If
Next I

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dan, this works perfectly except for when the AutoFilter bit is included. It doesn't like this line: `.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Branch Not Open", Operator:=xlAnd` and gives me run-time error 'AutoFilter Method of Range Class Failed'. I thought it might be because Column C's type is Date, so I changed it to General & Text just to test, but it gave the same. Then I changed the Criteria1 to just say "Branch" or "Open" but that also gave the same error. If I exclude this bit, the correct dates are removed.

Comment: Hey @Lisa, the 1004 error might occur if "Branch Not Open" is missing from column C (as in it's already been filtered out by a previous action). I updated the code above to check for that possibility... Hopefully that works!

Comment: Hi Dan, I checked that "Branch Not Open" was still in Col C, and then I ran the updated code. This then gave me runtime "Application-defined or object-defined error". So I tried something different - I copied all the data as values into a brand new excel doc (no VLOOKUPS and IFs etc) and your code worked perfectly!!!

Comment: Hey @Lisa, that's great to hear -- so happy we were able to help, and even more happy the process was clear enough that you could troubleshoot on your own. If this answer was the best one, please mark it as correct so other S.O. searchers can reference it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use it upon opening file, you should specify the sheet you want it to run as upon opening file there is no range/sheet selected there for error '1004' ;) for ex.

```
'Following line needs to be defined more accurately
    Range("C" & I).Value
'Redefine
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & I).Value
```

Other wise the following will work, add the DateValue() to make the comparioson with the date values -

```
    If DateValue(Range("C" & I).Value) > DateValue(Date) Then Rows(I).Delete
```

### The solution

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim LR As Long, I As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

LR = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For I = LR To 1 Step -1
    If IsDate(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & I).Value) Then
        If DateValue(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & I).Value) > DateValue(Date) Then Rows(I).Delete
    End If
Next I

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, my code should look like this

`Sub DeleteCells()
Dim LR As Long, I As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
LR = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For I = LR To 1 Step -1
    If DateValue(Range("C" & I).Value) > DateValue(Date) Then Rows(I).Delete
Next I
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub`
Get Run-time error 9 - Subscript out of range. This seems to be problem? `If DateValue(Range("C" & I).Value) > DateValue(Date) Then Rows(I).Delete`

Comment: Just saw your screen cap, there will be problems if all the values are not dates so you could check the format by using **IsDate(Range("C" & I).Value)** to evaluate if or not to delete the line. Also all the other ranges need to be defined more accurately so also the ones used inside DateValue() etc.

Comment: I refurbished my answer, there you can see the full code and solution.

Comment: Because I'm new to this, I'm probably doing something silly. I have removed all text from the column. Please check error: http://postimg.org/image/ikba5xtvj/    
When hitting debug: http://postimg.org/image/h53wxhlkd/

Comment: Hi it's because your "sheet4" is actually named "Clocking Exceptions", so changing the sheet4 to match the name shoudl do it. Also if you use Private Sub Workbook_Open() you should place this into "ThisWorkbook" and not to module, if you use Sub DeleteCells() then it goes in to a module-

Comment: @DanWagner has many good points in his answer. One of the most helpful line of code is **Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Clocking Exceptions")**. I can't endorse enough for the use of setting pointers. The longer your line of code is the more you gain for not having to go trough the trouble of correcting each line where you referred directly to the workbook/sheet etc.